# Matplotlib scatter now takes three arguments?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, theano

I wrote a short script to display some graphs:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = gen_spiral(label=0, dt=0,     n_samples=100, )
    p2 = gen_spiral(label=1, dt=np.pi, n_samples=100, )
    print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("p1",   type(p1),   str(np.shape(p1)),   len(p1),    str(p1)))
    print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("p2",   type(p2),   str(np.shape(p2)),   len(p2),    str(p2)))


    a = np.arange(1,20,1) 
    b = np.arange(1,20,1) 
    c = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    d = np.sin(2*np.pi*c)

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
    ax1.scatter(a,b) 
    ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(122)
    ax2.scatter(c,d)
```

and it worked fine. However, when I changed the function to display MY data:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
ax1.scatter(p1)
```

It gave me an error that shouldn't exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Theano--PlotSet--ME01.py", line 53, in <module>
    ax1.scatter(p1) 
TypeError: scatter() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

That's not true: Scatter takes 3 arguments, and p1 has two parts:

```
    jason@jason-HP-43299:~/Programs/MachineLearning/SectionOne$ python TheanoPS00.py
    Array:   p1
    Type:   <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    Shape:   (100, 2)
    Length:   100
    Data:   [[-0.0617  0.0534]
     [ 0.0299  0.0913]
     [ 0.0094  0.157 ]
     [ 0.1057  0.1535]
     [ 0.1412  0.2741]
     [ 0.0851  0.1426]
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: If p1 has two parts, you need to pass each part as a separate positional argument, as required by the spec: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scatter` function you call here is a class method of the axes. It's signature is
[`scatter(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs)`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3760), having 3 positional arguments, the class argument `self` being the first, which you provide implicitely by calling it as a method of the axes instance.

Knowing this one can translate the error message into *"scatter() takes at least 2 user specified arguments (1 given)"*. This makes sense, because `scatter(p1)` uses 1 argument.

What you would need to do is split your array up into the `x` and `y` arrays,

```
ax1.scatter(p1[:,0], p1[:,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `p1` has two parts, you need to pass each part as a separate positional argument, as required by [the spec](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

This `TypeError` you're seeing is strictly looking at the number of arguments defined in the source code and comparing it to your use of the function.

Presumably you want the x and y of the `shape`, so you could do:

```
ax1.scatter(p1.shape[0], p1.shape[1])
```